# Subtrair sabados, domingos e datas especificas de outra tabela

Tags: sql-server

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma tabela: **feriadosNacionais**

- id
- data
- dascricao

Tenho uma tabela: **feriados** (avulsos e emendas)

- id
- data
- descricao

em outra tabela: **obrigacao** (onde através de uma data informada pelo usuário "prazoLegal" eu teria que calcular -5 dias tirando sabados, domingos e caso tenho alguma data avulsa na tabela de feriado, e dar a dataCorrigida.

Exemplo.

prazoLegal = 26/01/2017

dataCorrigida teria que ser = 18/01/2017

ou seja (-8) pois 25/01/2017 é feriado em SP e esta na tabela de feriados avulsos e 21/01/2017 é sabado e 22/01/2017 é domingo.

Comment: Consegue colocar o script de criação das suas tabelas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tomei a liberdade de não ler a tabela para verificar os sábados e domingos, pois existe uma função no sql server para isso. veja se resolve seu problema.

```
DECLARE @data DATE = '2017-01-26'
DECLARE @DiasUteisRemovidos INTEGER = 0
DECLARE @DiaSemana INTEGER 
DECLARE @feriado INT
DECLARE @emenda INT

WHILE @DiasUteisRemovidos < 5
BEGIN
    --subtrai 1 dia da data final
    SET @data = DATEADD(day, -1, @data)
    --pega o dia da semana que a data cai
    SET @DiaSemana =  DATEPART(dw,@data)
    --Verifica se é feriado na tabela de feriados ou emenda na tabela de emendas
    SELECT @feriado = COUNT(*) FROM feriados WHERE data = @data
    SELECT @emenda = COUNT(*) FROM emendas WHERE data = @data
    --Se a data estiver entre domingo e sábado e não for feriado nem emenda, conta que removeu 1 dia útil
    IF @DiaSemana > 1 AND @DiaSemana < 7 AND @feriado = 0 AND @emenda = 0
    SET @DiasUteisRemovidos +=1
END

PRINT CONVERT(char(30), @data)
```

O último PRINT é apenas para efeito de teste. Em produção provavelmente esse código estará em uma Stored Procedure eu imagino.

Comment: Perfeito Washington, vou adequar ao meu senário muito obrigado.